# Please how do i select from database where station = e.station in this php code?

Tags: php, sql, database

This is my code below

```
<?php
include 'config1.php';

$sql = "select e.id, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.title, e.station, e.picture, count(r.id) reportCount " . 
        "from employee e left join employee r on r.managerId = e.id " .
        "group by e.id order by e.lastName, e.firstName " .
        "where e.station=:station group by e.lastName order by e.lastName, e.firstName";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql); 
    $stmt->bindParam("station", $_GET['station']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $employees = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbh = null;
    echo '{"items":'. json_encode($employees) .'}'; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}

?>
```

This is the code i'm trying to edit, This one just displays all the data in the database, what i want is to display the data where station = e.station.

```
<?php
include 'config1.php';

$sql = "select e.id, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.title, e.picture, count(r.id) reportCount " . 
        "from employee e left join employee r on r.managerId = e.id " .
        "group by e.id order by e.lastName, e.firstName";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
    $employees = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbh = null;
    echo '{"items":'. json_encode($employees) .'}'; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}


?>
```

**The error code i'm getting is this 
{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where e.station=:station group by e.lastName order by e.lastName, e.firstName' at line 1}}**

Comment: I believe your WHERE clause must come before the group by clause

Comment: ^ he would be right.

Comment: You also have duplicated group by clauses

Comment: Thanks, You were all right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "select e.id, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.managerId, e.title, e.station, e.picture, count(r.id) reportCount " . 
        "from employee e left join employee r on r.managerId = e.id " . "where e.station=:station group by e.lastName,e.id order by e.lastName,e.firstName";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);  
    $stmt->bindParam("station", $_GET['station']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $employees = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbh = null;
    echo '{"items":'. json_encode($employees) .'}'; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
```

`$_GET['station']` is gotten from the URL like **https://www.example.com?station=xyx**

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL is valid according to:

```
select e.id,e.firstName,e.lastName, e.title,e.station,e.picture,count(r.id)  reportCount from employee e left join employee r on r.managerId = e.id where e.station = station group by e.lastName,e.id order by e.lastName,e.firstName
```

[SQL SYNTAX checker](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/)
This also follows the MariaDB syntax: [Click here for documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/select/)

I'm not exactly sure what `:station` was supposed todo.
You also had multiple group by and order by clauses.